# Training books or sites

Tags: узус

I'm new to Russian and started learning it about 2 or 3 months ago. Till now I've been using Duolingo to learn Russian, and as you may all know, Duolingo is not the site for 'Grammar' and I had to learn that the hard way. I've also tried using some sites like masterrussian, russianforeveryone and other similar sites, but I feel these sites are a little too advanced for a beginner like me (this may not be the case for everyone).
I just really want to know if any of you know any nice site where everything is taught about Russian, Free of cost and clearly(eg: gender, the cases, conjugations, etc) which is easy for people like me to understand.
If possible please mention any Russian learning books which includes vocabulary and grammar which is available on Amazon.
Thank you

Comment: Actually, both sites have basic topics. It might seem harder than doulinguo, as they won't give you impression that you can read something easy super-quickly, but it should be like that if you are just starting to learn a language. And don't forget, Russian is not a simple language :)